# Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.128.3' in Laravel project in Docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I try to set up Laravel project in Docker.
My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=identy
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=654321
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - identy-network

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=654321
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=654321
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=identy
    volumes:
      - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - ./data/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    networks:
      - identy-network

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  identy-network:
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y vim git zlib1g-dev mariadb-client libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=on' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >>  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf \
    && mv /var/www/html /var/www/public \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
    | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && echo "AllowEncodedSlashes On" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

.env:

```
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=identy
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=654321
...
```

When I run 
**docker exec identy-api_web_1 php artisan migrate**
I get error:
**  Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.144.3' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = identy and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
**

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think, You don't have permission to access the database from remote host on the mysql server. You need to allow access remotely to root from any host on the mysql server.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.144.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the volumes data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define `MYSQL_USER=root`. Try this one (it creates identy db as well):

```
db:
  image: mysql:8.0
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=654321
  networks:
    - identy-network
  volumes:
    - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
  entrypoint: sh -c "
    echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS identy;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'm not sure if I understand well: I changed docker-compose yml according to your suggestion and I still get error:  'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.80.3' (using password: YES) '    when I try to execute 'docker exec identy-api_web_1 php artisan migrate'

Comment: Hm, you have rebuilt and set up again db service after changing the docker-comose.yml, right?